# MVVM Light - SimpleIoC. Removing an instance from the cache unregisters the class

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

Reading the documentation on the MVVM Light SimpleIoC class for unregistering an instance. The document states:

```
Unregister<TClass>(TClass)
```

> Removes the given instance from the cache. The class itself remains registered and can be used to create other instances.

But this documentation doesn't seem to reflect the actual SimpleIoC implementation. When I call  `Unregister<TClass>(TClass)` the instance is removed from the cache successfully, but the class is also unregistered from IoC.  The documentation suggests that this overload of `Unregister` should not do this.

```
Ioc.Register<MockDto>();
var instance = Ioc.GetInstance<MockDto>();
Ioc.Unregister(instance);
var newInstance = IoC.GetInstance<MockDto>();
```

The second call to `IoC.GetInstance<MockDto>();` throws an ActivationException: 'Type not found in cache without a key'.

Is my understanding and usage of the `Unregister<T>(T instance)` wrong, or is this an unresolved bug?

I am using version 5.0.2.0 of 'MVVM Light Libraries Only' in a Portable Class Library.

edit: Link SimpleIoC class documentation http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/e2774a68-2132-6ab6-61a4-2eb3e8ae811b.htm

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in the version of MVVMLight. It was recently fixed in version 5.1 - see this post for the bug discussion:
https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/483764